# No sound on my external USB SoundBlaster Audigy 2 ZS Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, usb, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a problem with my USB SoundBlaster Audigy 2 ZS on Ubuntu 22.04.
It is the first time I test it on Linux.
It seem to be detected :

```
cat /proc/asound/cards    
0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp    
                      LENOVO ...    
1 [Editor         ]: USB-Audio - SB Audigy 2 ZS Video Editor    
                      Creative Technology Ltd. SB Audigy 2 ZS Video Editor at usb-0000:00:14.0-1.5, f
```

And :

```
aplay -l  
**** Liste des périphériques matériels PLAYBACK **** carte 0 : sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], périphérique 0 : HDA Analog (*) []    
Sous-périphériques : 0/1   Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0 carte 0  
: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], périphérique 1 : HDA Digital (*) []    
Sous-périphériques : 1/1   Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0 carte 0  
: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], périphérique 3 : HDMI1 (*) []    
Sous-périphériques : 1/1   Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0 carte 0  
: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], périphérique 4 : HDMI2 (*) []    
Sous-périphériques : 1/1   Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0 carte 0  
: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], périphérique 5 : HDMI3 (*) []    
Sous-périphériques : 1/1   Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0 carte 1  
: Editor [SB Audigy 2 ZS Video Editor], périphérique 0 : USB Audio  
[USB Audio]   Sous-périphériques : 0/1   Sous-périphérique #0 :  
subdevice #0 carte 1 : Editor [SB Audigy 2 ZS Video Editor],  
périphérique 1 : USB Audio [USB Audio #1]   Sous-périphériques : 1/1  
Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0 carte 1 : Editor [SB Audigy 2 ZS
Video Editor], périphérique 2 : USB Audio [USB Audio #2]    
Sous-périphériques : 1/1   Sous-périphérique #0 : subdevice #0
```

AND

lsusb

```
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 041e:3070 Creative Technology, Ltd   
Bus 003 Device 015: ID 041e:3061 Creative Technology, Ltd SoundBlaster Audigy 2 ZS Video Editor  
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 041e:3050 Creative Technology, Ltd
```

BUT
I have no sound, but I can choose it and configure the different mod 5.1 ...
VLC see it to, and I can choose it.

On /var/log, I have this error message :

```
pulseaudio[2083]: Volume element 'Headphone' has 9 channels. That's too much! I can't handle that!

kernel: [441712.418905] usb 3-3.1.5: 2:10: usb_set_interface failed (-32) **-> multiple time**  

systemd-udevd[1169172]: controlC1: Process '/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 1' failed with exit code 99.
```

When I connect it :

```
kernel: [442938.834466] usb 3-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd  
kernel: [442938.940075] usb 3-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=041e, idProduct=3061, bcdDevice= 1.00  
kernel: [442938.940081] usb 3-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0  
kernel: [442938.940084] usb 3-1.5: Product: SB Audigy 2 ZS Video Editor  
kernel: [442938.940086] usb 3-1.5: Manufacturer: Creative Technology Ltd.  
kernel: [442938.969725] usb 3-1.5: 3:2 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442939.190095] usb 3-1.5: 3:3 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442939.398448] usb 3-1.5: 3:4 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442939.619329] usb 3-1.5: 3:5 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442939.827932] usb 3-1.5: 3:6 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442940.465603] usb 3-1.5: 3:2 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442940.465612] usb 3-1.5: 3:3 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442940.465614] usb 3-1.5: 3:4 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442940.465616] usb 3-1.5: 3:5 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442940.465618] usb 3-1.5: 3:6 : format type 0 is detected, processed as PCM  
kernel: [442940.836943] usb 3-1.5: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=960), cval->res is probably wrong.  
kernel: [442940.836946] usb 3-1.5: [31] FU [Delay Control] ch = 9, val = 0/960/1*
```

The power blue led start blinking when I connect it. Normally it have to stay on.
The optical out blink a little bit, I think it was data exchange.

Do you have idea about the errors ?
Thanks in advance
David

Comment: Thanks Pilot6, it is not easy this format !  
I have try on a fresh install on a VM. I have the same messages.  
  
I have try on my computer, with the profil Sortie Stéréo Analogique (Stereo Analog Output, I think) in the Hardware tab. And in Output tab : Headphones2, the sound work with the headphone on the headphone connector. But with or without headphone it is the same, the Jack on Line Out 1 connector never have sound.  
  
The power led still blue with the Headphone option.

Comment: With Gnome Alsa Mixer it works :)  The blinking is probably for mute. I have try to mute, unmute, and it work with 5.1 configuration, but I test it only this stereo.

Comment: Can we have a software or driver, to get volume button and other switch to work ? Now buttons (and probably remote command) have no effect :(